# Receiving router parameter in new router

Tags: angular

I've been trying to read this https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

but it has alot of information and not what I simply need.
I am sending a parameter from another component and in the previous router I just used this:

```
if (params.get('receiver'))
        {
        this.addRecipient(params.get('receiver'));
        this.showNewMsgForm = true;
        }
```

in the new router there is no RouterParams and I have no idea how do I get the parameters.
How I can get the **receiver** parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was in the link you provided...

```
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
   let receiver = this.route.snapshot.params['receiver'];
}
```

or

```
private sub: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
  this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
     let receiver = params['receiver'];
   });
}
```